BFXImpliedSwap and other bbg functions in blpapi Python
i'm trying to find a way to get FX specific bbg API functions such as the BFxImpliedSwap working in Python's blpapi.
in excel, to get an FX Implied Yield for a currency, one can use the following function (which could also be more granual e.g. one can select specific yield curves for both USD and non-USD legs)
=BFxImpliedSwap("KRW", "SP", "1M", "TermCurrencyImpliedMidYield", "MarketType=Onshore","ForwardSource=BGN", "GlobalSettings=True")
would love to hear how to get this working in python as well, thanks.
the usual fx implied yield function such as "EURI6M Curncy" works well, but i'd like to be able to specify the other curves of the yield implied by an fx swap.
df = blp.bdp('EURI1M Curncy','PX_MID')
print(df)

It is far from straightforward to achieve this in Python, as the Excel function is using the undocumented //blp/fxap subscription service, whereas all the common Python wrappers assume the subscription is to //blp/mktdata.

Behind the scenes, Excel is converting the parameters of =BFxImpliedSwap() to the far-from-obvious subscription: //blp/fxap/BFxImpliedSwap/KRW?MarketType=Onshore&ForwardSource=BGN&GlobalSettings=TRUE&NEARFARPAIRS=SP|1M&FIELDS=TermCurrencyImpliedMidYield

If the OP has the inclination, they can use this function to mimic the Excel BFxImpliedSwap in Python. It uses the xbbg package to manage the Bloomberg session lifetime but otherwise uses the low-level blpapi. It involves a  subscription to the undocumented //blp/fxap service.
from xbbg.core import conn
from blpapi import Event,SubscriptionList,SubscriptionPreprocessMode

def BFxImpliedSwap(ccy,startTenor,endTenor,fields,options):
    resultDict={}

    def tryFloat(val):
        v = val
        if isinstance(val,str): #try to convert any strings to floats
            try: v = float(val)   
            except: pass
        return v    

    def handleEvent(evt):
        if evt.eventType() == Event.TIMEOUT:
            return False

        if evt.eventType() == Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
            retDict={}
            for msg in evt:
                cid = msg.correlationId().value()
                if cid in resultDict:
                    elt = msg.getElement('data')[0].getElement('value').getElement('tupleVal')
                    for eltVal in elt:
                        nm = eltVal.getElementAsString('name')
                        val = eltVal.getElement('value').getElement(0).toPy()
                        retDict[nm] = tryFloat(val)
                    resultDict[cid] = retDict
                    return False

        elif evt.eventType() == Event.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS:
            for msg in evt:
                if msg.messageType() == 'SubscriptionFailure':
                    reason = msg.getElement('reason').toPy()
                    cid=msg.correlationId().value()
                    resultDict[cid]= {'error':reason}
                    return False
            
        return True

    topic = f'//blp/fxap/BFxImpliedSwap/{ccy}'

    options['NEARFARPAIRS']=f'{startTenor}|{endTenor}'
    optionString = '&'.join([f'{k}={options[k]}' for k in options.keys()])

    sub_list = SubscriptionList()
    sub_list.add(topic=topic,fields=fields,options=optionString)

    cid = sub_list.correlationIdAt(0).value()
    resultDict[cid]=None

    session = conn.bbg_session()
    subscribeResult = session.subscribe(sub_list,mode=SubscriptionPreprocessMode.RETURN_INDIVIDUAL_ERRORS)

    if len(subscribeResult)==0: #Subscription pre-processing successful
        bContinue=True

        while bContinue:
            bContinue = handleEvent(session.nextEvent(timeout=2000))

        session.unsubscribe(sub_list)
        return resultDict[cid]
    else:
        return subscribeResult

Usage:
ccy = 'KRW'
start='SP'
end='1M'
fields=['TermCurrencyImpliedMidYield','TermCurrencyImpliedBidYield']
options = {'MarketType':'Onshore','ForwardSource':'BGN','GlobalSettings':'True'}

res = BFxImpliedSwap(ccy,start,end,fields,options)

for f in fields:
    print(f,res[f])

which yields the result (at time of writing):
TermCurrencyImpliedMidYield 3.3168
TermCurrencyImpliedBidYield 2.9028

